# App launches in simulator and preview but not on real iPhone or iPad

Tags: swiftui, xcode11, ios13

I try to create an app with the new SwiftUI framework and it works fine in the preview and the simulators. But when I connect my iPhone (XR) or iPad (6th Gen) (both running iOS 13 beta 2), the app just shows a white or black screen (depending on dark mode toggled on or off).

Xcode says 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' so I googled a bit and I already tried using Zombie objects. No success.

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(pindata) { pin in
                NavigationButton(destination: PinDetail(pin: pin, amount: UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: pin.color))) {
                    PinRow(pin: pin)
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Pins"))
        }
    }
}
```

The error 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' occurs in line 8 of the snippet.

I expected the app to run exactly like in the simulator but I get this error in the console:

```
2019-06-19 17:32:59.083958+0200 Pins[894:85155] [Assert] COMPATIBILITY BUG IN CLIENT OF UIKIT: Moving method canvasToolbar from UICanvas to UIWindowScene
2019-06-19 17:32:59.084270+0200 Pins[894:85155] [Assert] Registering Canvas Component Class _UICanvasUserActivityManager, please update to Frame Components
2019-06-19 17:32:59.089296+0200 Pins[894:85155] [Assert] Calling deprecated SPI on UICanvas. This method and class will dissapear prior to GM
2019-06-19 17:32:59.091533+0200 Pins[894:85155] [TraitCollection] Class _UISheetPresentationController overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.
2019-06-19 17:32:59.091575+0200 Pins[894:85155] [TraitCollection] Class _UIRootPresentationController overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.
2019-06-19 17:32:59.103592+0200 Pins[894:85155] [TraitCollection] Class UIPopoverPresentationController overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.
(lldb)
```